# $.getJSON on chrome extension fails to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension, and want to be able to get a profile picture from a username. Unfortunately, there isn't an api for the website and there is no correlation between the profile URL and the profile name. I figured I could hijack the search ajax and use it to achieve my goal. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. I've added the permissions, and it isn't running in a content script, but it's still not working.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.website.com/user/search",{user:name},function(a){
    alert(1);
    alert(a.data);
});
```

It's failing silently, as nothing is happing. Yet, I can't figure out why.
The json I should be receiving from the call (browsed to the site manually) is:
{"error":false,"action":null,"one":true,"data":143217}
Unfortunately it's not working. JSONP isn't an option, as the site obviously has no need of supporting it, so help me please. I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: I see the problem. When I try to do the request I'm being redirected to user/search ( no ?user) which fails.

Comment: Is your script on the same domain as the one you're trying to query?

Comment: No, but it doesn't have to be for a chrome extension if you specify the correct permissions.

Comment: Have you looked at what's being returned from the page you're querying by looking at "Network" under Developer Tools?

Comment: Please, elaborate as to what is returned from those two requests.

Comment: A failed request that's just website.com/user/search, and a successful request that goes at website.com/user/search?user=test

Comment: Ok, that's not what was returned, though, that's the requested URL. What was returned? If you click on the each request, you should be presented with a detailed view including anything returned from the request.

Comment: Nothing under the response tab, and the same response headers as those I got when I browsed to it manually.

Comment: Also, it waited for 310 milliseconds to receive a response, which is strange.

Comment: If you aren't getting a response from the server, it could be a multitude of issues. You need to provide more information, specifically a jsfiddle.net with your code, if you would like to get better help.

Comment: What I posted was essentially all my code. However, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgGmu/1/

Comment: jQuery's AJAX functions return a [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), so try adding `.fail(function(xhr, err, ex) { console.error(err, ex); })` after `$.getJSON(...)`  to see the actual error message.

Comment: The error message being returned, is: "error". Quite useful.

Comment: I edited the `fail` function.  There may be a more useful Exception passed as the third argument.

Comment: I've also  added something to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you're trying to reach requires authentication before allowing a search to occur. You won't get a response from your ajax request, because the server is looking for a session with login credentials to allow the search to happen. Because your ajax is not authenticated, and does not have the session established, your request doesn't "fail", it is simply getting the server's 302 redirect response.

You would need to 'sign in' to the page you are trying to query in order to establish the session and any necessary variables before you would be able to proceed with your user search.

Answer (score 0):

It could be entirely possible that the website's search API isn't returning the `Content-type` header as `text/json`, which is required for `$.getJSON` to function correctly.

Try simply using `$.get` and calling `JSON.parse` on the returned data.

Comment: But, it is returning the content-type as text/html if that's important to know.